# Как запарсить цены с auto.ru?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

пытаюсь запарсить инфу. Получается все кроме цены

пример кода:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

CSV = 'cards.csv'
HOST = 'https://auto.ru'
URL = 'https://auto.ru/moskva/cars/toyota/rav_4/all/'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    }

def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    r.encoding='utf-8'
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='ListingItem-module__container')
    cars = []

    for item in items:
        cars.append(
            {
                'title' : item.find('a', class_='Link ListingItemTitle-module__link').get_text(),
                'link_product':item.find('a', class_='Link ListingItemTitle-module__link').get('href'),
                'year' : item.find('div', class_='ListingItem-module__year').get_text(),
                'price' : item.find('div', class_='ListingItemPrice').get_text()
            }
        )
        
    return cars

# html = get_html(URL)
# print(get_content(html.text))

def save_doc(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['модель', 'ссылка на продукт', 'год выпуска', 'цена'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'], item['link_product'], item['year'], item['price']])

def parser():
    PAGENATION = 2
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cars = []
        for page in range(1, PAGENATION):
            print(f'парсим страницу: {page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page' : page})
            cars.extend(get_content(html.text))
            save_doc(cars, CSV)
           
    else:
        print('error')

parser()
```

выдает ошибку:

File "C:\Users\guzairovt\scripts\parser\auto_ru.py", line 35, in get_content
'price' : item.find('div', class_='ListingItemPrice').get_text()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0):

В таких ситуациях рекомендую следующие:

- Проверить, точно ли данный элемент на странице существует
- Убедиться в том что сайт не использует ajax подгрузку
- Проверить не обновился ли сайт (если парсер старый)

Скорее всего на сайте именно ajax, по этому рекомендую использовать selenium библиотеку для избежания таких ошибок

Comment: По 1и3 пунктам все проверено - элемент цена на странице есть, парсер свежий. По второму пункту затрудняюсь ответить - не знаю что это, и как проверить

Comment: Попробуйте получить div в котором хранятся данные, и посмотреть что с этим элементом не так. Если увидите там что-то на подобии "spiner" - это и есть подгрузка